# Wordpress - Display posts of a category as a result of a search - Archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

In my news page (home.php) I have the search by category widget (dropdown) that will lead me to a page with the result of my research for a specific category (archive.php).
Let's say for example, that I chose "Events" in the dropdown list, I'll be redirected to a page where only the posts within the "Events" category are displayed.

A few years ago, I took a plugin for displaying my posts in the same page, but now I'm putting back pagination but I have a problem: I can't find how to display only the posts of the category resulting of my search. For now, it displays all the posts.

I've done some research about it, tried a lot of solutions, tried to put back the classic code of an archive page (without any success) and went to this Wordpress page about get_the_category but I can't seem to find anything conclusive: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

Now my code is completely a mess and tbh I have no clue of what I'm doing anymore...
Plus I want to display only 8 posts per page, giving me more complications.

Here is what I have now

```
<div>
<?php
   $cats = get_categories();
   foreach ($cats as $cat) {
      $args = array(
         'post_type'         => 'post',
         'post_status'       => 'publish',
         'paged'             => $paged,
         'posts_per_page'    => 8
      );
      $temp = $wp_query;
      $wp_query= null;
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post($cat->cat_ID); ?>

        <div> Here is my post </div>

      <?php endwhile; } ?>
</div>
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
      'mid_size'  => 2
) ); ?>
<?php $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp;
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are already on the category page, you should simply retrieve the category name and pass it to your WP_Query args, which will filter all the posts to be displayed by category!

```
<?php

// Retrieve current category name
$categoryName = get_the_category()[0]->name;

// Set args for query and pass category name
$args = [
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'    => 8,
    'category_name'=> $categoryName
];

// Initiate WP Query
$wpQuery = new WP_Query($args);

// Loop through all posts in the query
while ($wpQuery->have_posts()) {
    $wpQuery->the_post(); ?>
    <div>Your post</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks for your help